# Disable Esc close for colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using the [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) plugin for jQuery.

I know I don't have to have a close button, and `overlayClose: false` will prevent the window from being closed by clicking the overlay.

Is there a way to remove the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key-listener event?

Comment: You should select @Roland's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at the source, the escape key is bound to the `keydown.cbox_close` event from line 165:

```
    // Set Navigation Key Bindings
    $(document).bind("keydown.cbox_close", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    cboxPublic.close();
            }
    ...
```

You could comment out that binding, or use it for some other purpose.

Comment: Use the built in option instead, see Roland's answer.

Answer (score 27):

property -> escKey:false

Comment: This is actually the preferred method, since upgrading Colorbox to a different version would affect your source modifications (from karim79's answer). From the Colorbox documentation, "escKey:true  If false, will disable closing colorbox on esc keypress." http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0):

As `overlayClose: false`, for ESC you can make `escKey:false`